# How to render a custom user field in comments?

Tags: 8, theming, users

I want to render a custom user field from the commentator's profile in comment.twig programatically. How to realize that?

Comment: What am I doing wrong?`function mytheme_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
    $comment = $variables['elements']['#comment'];
    $variables['twitter'] = $comment->getOwner()->field_twitter->value;
    $variables['facebook] = $comment->getOwner()->field_rol->value;
}`

Comment: This code does not work too `function mytheme_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
    if ($comment = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('comment')) {
        $variables['twitter'] = $comment->getOwner()->field_twitter->value;
        $variables['facebook'] = $comment->getOwner()->field_rol->value;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_comment().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  $comment = $variables['elements']['#comment'];
  $commentOwner = $comment->getOwner();
  if ($commentOwner){
    $variables['twitter'] = $commentOwner->get('field_twitter')->getValue()[0]['value'];
    $variables['facebook'] = $commentOwner->get('field_facebook')->getValue()[0]['value'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Not works too...

Comment: did you print the `$twitter` and `$facebook` what you get ??

Comment: I print {{ twitter }} in my comment.twig and nothing

Comment: did you rebuild the cache ?

Comment: you are welcome, i'm glad that help, good luck .